# jQuery Button: Play/Pause Audio AND switch Images

Tags: jquery, image, button, audio, toggle

I am trying to make a button that toggles play and pause of an audio-Tag. When it plays the image should show an active speaker, when it's paused the speaker should be appear with an X.

[Sound off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvNz8.png)
[Sound on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFF2f.png)

The code below is able to toggle between the images but how do I add the option to play and pause when the images change?

Thanks for your answers!

```html
<!-- Audio --> >
<img src="/media/sound_off.png" alt="Play Music" id="playbutton" onclick="change();">
<audio id="background-music" src="/media/sjorisar-intro.mp3"></audio>


<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var image_tracker = 'off';

  function change() {
    var image = document.getElementById('playbutton');
    if (image_tracker == 'off') {
      image.src = '/media/sound_on.png';
      image_tracker = 'on';
    } else {
      image.src = '/media/sound_off.png';
      image_tracker = 'off';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```js
var mPlayer = document.getElementById("background_music"); 
var mPlayAction = document.getElementById("playbutton"); 

var isPlaying = false;

function playAudio() { 
    mPlayer.play(); 
    isPlaying = true;
    mPlayAction.src = "https://findicons.com/files/icons/1676/primo/128/button_blue_pause.png";
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
    mPlayer.pause();
    isPlaying = false;
    mPlayAction.src = "https://findicons.com/files/icons/1676/primo/128/button_blue_play.png";
} 
function HandleAudio(){
  if(isPlaying == true){
    //Playing already Pause it
    pauseAudio();
  }else{
    //Play the music
    playAudio();
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://findicons.com/files/icons/1676/primo/128/button_blue_play.png" alt="Play Music" id="playbutton" onclick="HandleAudio()">

<audio id="background_music">
  <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .toggle() function.

```js
$("#p1").toggle(function() {
    //$(this).html('<img src="play.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>');
    $(this).html('Test 2');
}, function() {
$(this).html('Test 3');
    //$(this).html('<img src="pause.png" width="60px" height="60px"/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p1">Test 1</div>

$(this).html('test2');


<!--<img src="/media/sound_off.png" alt="Play Music" id="playbutton" onclick="change();"> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to play and pause the audio

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var image_tracker = 'off';

  function change() {
    var image = document.getElementById('playbutton');
    var audio= document.getElementById('background-music');
    if (image_tracker == 'off') {
      image.src = '/media/sound_on.png';
      image_tracker = 'on';
      audio.play();
    } else {
      image.src = '/media/sound_off.png';
      image_tracker = 'off';
      audio.pause();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works as well :-D